# How to build and sign a transaction to deploy a contract

Tags: web3js, transactions, private-key

I am trying to generate a transaction to deploy a smart contract on the chain and to sign it with web3js.

My problem is that I have no idea how to build the transaction object needed for the signTransaction function.

I first tried to create an object using the contract.deploy() function (without sending), but the transaction object needs a gas property, that the deploy() function does not create.

How do I create a transaction object that deploy a contract and how do I sign it with a private key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working with the following method:
First, get the contract instance without specifying an address (according to documentation, it is optional):

```
let abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(tokenAbi).toString());
        let contractInstance = new web3g.eth.Contract(abi);
```

Then deploy the contract WITHOUT sending it and use the encodeABI function:

```
let deploy = newContract.deploy({
              data: bytecode,
              arguments: [my args here
}).encodeABI();
```

Build a transaction object using the deploy object and other properties as follow:

```
 let gas = parseInt(4000000).toString(16);
 let gasPrice = parseInt(4000000000).toString(16);
    let transactionObject = {
                     gas: gas,
                     gasPrice: gasPrice,
                     data: deploy,
                     from: req.body.sender_address
                                                };
```

**Note: If you don't encode to hex, geth will return you an error saying it cannot parse from whatever to some Golang type**

Then you ca nsign and send the signed transaction

```
     web3g.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionObject, req.body.private_key, function (error, signedTx) {
                         if (error) {
                         //do stuff
                } else {  
                      web3g.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
.on('confirmation', function (number) {//dostuff});
```

Comment: I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined ` at line of: `web3g.eth.accounts.signTransaction `, why?

Answer (score 0):

[web3js-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw) node package provides set of helper functions which allow you to deploy a contract easily.

Answer (score -3):

All the answers to your question are answered in the documentation, its full of examples.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html

Here is an example I got from this resource 
https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/contract_info.html

```
source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
// compile with solc
 contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
// create contract object
 var MyContract = eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition)
// extracts info from contract, save the json serialisation in the given file, 
 contenthash = admin.saveInfo(contract.info, "~/dapps/shared/contracts/test/info.json")
// send off the contract to the blockchain
MyContract.new({from: primaryAccount, data: contract.code}, function(error, contract){
if(!error && contract.address) {
// calculates the content hash and registers it with the code hash in `HashReg`
// it uses address to send the transaction. 
// returns the content hash that we use to register a url
admin.register(primaryAccount, contract.address, contenthash)
// here you deploy ~/dapps/shared/contracts/test/info.json to a url
admin.registerUrl(primaryAccount, hash, url)
}
});
```

Comment: I understand that. But what I want is creating the transaction object that says "deploy the contract" but not deploying it yet. Use this tx object to sign it and then send it. But how do I hve to build the transaction object...?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: I got it working on my side, will propose an edit to your answer tomorow, thanks for your time

Comment: I added a new answer as yours is not similar.