# Is it possible to call a function of smart contract "without" installing "Geth" or "Parity"?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity

Is it possible to call a function of smart contract to send a transaction (for example, writing on the Ethereum blockchain) but "without" installing "Geth" or "Parity" clients?

In a more general question, is it possible to interact with Ethereum blockchain, without installing Geth or Parity?

Comment: You can interact to existing node like infura :)

Comment: Is it possible to use `infura` in a `micro-controller`, because of limitations of installing `Geth` or `Parity` on these devices? Thanks

Comment: It’s just a endpoint then you can connect to it via json rpc

Answer (score 1):

You can download the contract's code, and the part of the StateDB that this contract uses for storage, also the part of the SateDB of the addresses involved in contract calls, and then you can use `cmd/evm` binary to run this contract's code:

`cmd/evm run --input 0xa5e4d2b41223289af53234 --code 0xcontract'scode ....`

It is very hacky, but you asked if it is possible and that's how it is possible to do it without installing `Geth` or `Parity`.

Answer (score 1):

On the generic question - interacting with Ethereum without using a client, it depends on the definition of "interacting". If it is limited to sending transactions only, then the short answer is yes, provided one:

- has the account's private key
- know the account's nonce
- has the called contract's ABI (not needed for simple payment transactions).

With the above, a transaction can be constructed byte by byte. One actual example is [here](https://lsongnotes.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/signing-an-ethereum-transaction-the-hard-way/). The constructed "raw" transaction can be sent over with tools such as etherscan's [broadcaster](https://etherscan.io/pushTx) (well, in theory even this can be rid of, but then one will have to implement - at least partially - the [RLPx](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) protocol) .

In fact, this is what makes it hard to censor a blockchain transaction: one can always construct the transaction off-line, and send the bytes through a post (or even voice) to friends, who can then help push to the network.

Although, the problem is the "one-way" sending can be hardly called "interacting". To make things go two ways, a receiver is needed, which will need to check the validity of incoming messages. This, in turn, requires fully implementing the protocol. Now we have just brought back "the client".

For the original question, calling a contract's method without using geth or parity, the same bytes construction methodology from the aforementioned post can be used, although the contract ABI becomes necessary. See this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/35720/20451) for more details.